# PHP memory size exhausted in drupal

Tags: mysql, php, php-fpm, memcache, php-memcached

FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 137612647 bytes)

Already I increase 2 times in php.ini file. But again memory size exhausted happening. And also I got following error /app/source_code_shop/shop/sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/dmemcache.inc on line 64" while reading response header from upstream.

We can't fixed this solution. Is it memcache error or memcache module error or php coding problem. Please give me proper solution how can solve php memory exhaust problem in drupal.

Comment: You need to figure out what part of Drupal (or a theme or extension) uses so much memory. Our sister site [drupal.se] may be able to help you with this.

Comment: Are you working with large images, or big arrays, or what?

Comment: This problem is a FAQ with Drupal 9 and Composer - see [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors).